# How to access "__" (double underscore) variables in methods added to a class

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming

## Background

I wish to use a meta class in order to add helper methods based on the original class. If the method I wish to add uses `self.__attributeName` I get an `AttributeError` (because of name mangling) but for an existing identical method this isn't a problem.

## Code example

Here is a simplified example

```
# Function to be added as a method of Test
def newfunction2(self):
    """Function identical to newfunction"""
    print self.mouse
    print self._dog
    print self.__cat

class MetaTest(type):
    """Metaclass to process the original class and
    add new methods based on the original class
    """
    def __new__(meta, name, base, dct):
        newclass = super(MetaTest, meta).__new__(
                meta, name, base, dct
                )

        # Condition for adding newfunction2
        if "newfunction" in dct:
            print "Found newfunction!"
            print "Add newfunction2!"
            setattr(newclass, "newfunction2", newfunction2)

        return newclass

# Class to be modified by MetaTest
class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaTest

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cat = "cat"
        self._dog = "dog"
        self.mouse = "mouse"

    def newfunction(self):
        """Function identical to newfunction2"""
        print self.mouse
        print self._dog
        print self.__cat

T = Test()
T.newfunction()
T.newfunction2() # AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '__cat'
```

## Question

Is there a way of adding `newfunction2` that could use `self.__cat`?

(Without renaming `self.__cat` to `self._cat`.)

And maybe something more fundamental, why isn't `self.__cat` being treated in the same way for both cases since `newfunction2` is now part of `Test`?

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Name mangling happens when the methods in a class are compiled. Attribute names like `__foo` are turned in to `_ClassName__foo`, where `ClassName` is the name of the class the method is defined in. Note that you can use name mangling for attributes of other objects!

In your code, the name mangling in `newfunction2` doesn't work because when the function is compiled, it's not part of the class. Thus the lookups of `__cat` don't get turned into `__Test_cat` the way they did in `Test.__init__`. You could explicitly look up the mangled version of the attribute name if you want, but it sounds like you want `newfunction2` to be generic, and able to be added to multiple classes. Unfortunately, that doesn't work with name mangling.

Indeed, preventing code not defined in your class from accessing your attributes is the whole reason to use name mangling. Usually it's only worth bothering with if you're writing a proxy or mixin type and you don't want your internal-use attributes to collide with the attributes of the class you're proxying or mixing in with (which you won't know in advance).

Comment: In this docs tutorial of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/   . There is this code line ' Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)' and pub date year var has a double underscore, is this the same as you have mentioned?@Blckknght

Comment: @LordDraagon: No, that appears to be Django's own thing. Its spelling may be partly inspired by Python's native name mangling, but it's implemented separately, and has different meaning. I think the double underscores are sort of like dots in attribute notation (so `pub_date__year` is sort of like `pub_date.year`). I don't know enough about Django to give a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To answer both of your questions:

1. You will need to change `self.__cat` when you need to call it from `newfunction2` to `self._Test__cat` thanks to the name mangling rule.

---

2. [Python documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

> This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the
>   identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

Let me brake it down for you, it's saying that it doesn't matter where your interpreter is reading when it encounters a name mangled name. **The name will only be mangled *if* it occurs in the definition of a class**, which in your case, it's not. Since it's not directly "under" a class definition. So when it reads `self.__cat`, it's keeping it at `self.__cat`, **not** going to textually replace it with `self._Test__cat` since it isn't defined inside the`Test` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<Test instance>._Test__cat` to access the `__cat` attribute from the `Test` class. (where `<Test instance>` is replaced by `self` or any other instance of the `Test` class)

learn more in the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Comment: I thought of this, but since I am adding `newmethod2` as a method, I thought the behaviour should be the same. i.e. that I can access `self.__cat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private = 0 
    def __private_method(self):
        '''A private method via inheritance'''
        return ('{!r}'.format(self))
    def internal_method(self):
        return ('{!s}'.format(self))

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__private = 1
    def __private_method(self):
        return 'Am from class C'

c = C()
print(c.__dict__)
b = B()
print(b.__dict__)
print(b._B__private)
print(c._C__private_method())
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation for why this solves the original poster’s problem.