# Python: Show content of hidden parameters for debugging

Tags: python, class, debugging

my core question is: how can I visualize hidden parameters of a class for debugging?
I'm using spyder 3.6 for coding and have e.g. this test code:

```
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.__hiddenVar = number
        self.visibleVar = number
        print(str(self.__hiddenVar ) + 'at init')

    def plus_2_times_4(x):  
        return(4*(x + 2))

    def arithmetic(self):
        print(str(self.__hiddenVar ) + 'at arithmetic')
        return(ExampleClass.plus_2_times_4(self.__hiddenVar ))

instance = ExampleClass(number = 4)
instance.arithmetic()
```

Now I want to stop the run let's say at the printout of "arithmetic" and debug the content of "self".
When I run "self.visibleVar" in console window of spyder, it shows the conent, in this case "4".
When I do the same with "self.__hiddenVar" it throws an error: *** AttributeError: 'ExampleClass' object has no attribute '__hiddenVar'

Well, I understand why this is the case: it is a hidden variable and this is how it is supposed to be. But how can I debug in that situation? Do I have any possibility to show the content even though it is a hidden variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first thing, I would suggest you to read:

- [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)
- [How to access "__" (double underscore) variables in methods added to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114560/how-to-access-double-underscore-variables-in-methods-added-to-a-class)

To resume the content that you really need, I must say that the interpreter "transforms" `__hiddenvar` to `_ExampleClass__hiddenvar`.

Comment: This community is really awesome: I ask a question and get an answer within 5 minutes that is really helpful! Great and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Data4711, I had exactly your same reaction around a year ago! Check other StackExchange communities, like CodeReview, they will leave you amazed.